# MVC 3 Razor UTF character encoding issue

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, encoding, utf-8

I have an app and having character encoding problems, the app is in turkish and when i share a post on facebook

```
Foto**ÄŸ**raf yar**Ä±ÅŸ**masÄ±na bir fotoÄŸraf yÃ¼kledi. Sen de bir Macbook Air kazanmak iÃ§in konulu fotoÄŸrafÄ±nÄ± yÃ¼kle, hayatÄ±na cam kat
```

i get this text.

I got this text after i convert the encoding to UTF8-NO BOM.

so this worked in IE. however doesnt work in chrome and firefox.

If i use only UTF-8. so i dont use UTF-8 NO BOM

Then IE breaks and Chrome, FF works.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Would encoding html string work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encoding string worked in this case.